# how to make AWS dynamo db work in nodejs in using async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have this sample dynamo db create data code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
let awsConfig = {
    "region": "ap-south-1",
    "endpoint": "http://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
    "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "secretAccessKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
};
AWS.config.update(awsConfig);

let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log(docClient);

let save = function () {

    var input = {
        "task": "example-1@gmail.com"
    };
    var params = {
        TableName: "todos",
        Item:  input
    };
    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("error - " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));                      
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}



save();
```

Now I converted this into async-await form

```
const create = async (docClient,payload,tableName) =>{
    try {
        console.log(payload);
        const createdDoc = await docClient.put({TableName:tableName,Item:payload})
        console.log(createdDoc);
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(error); 
    }
}
        


create(docClient,{"task":"sample"},"todos")
```

This code neither gave me an error neither it add data into dynamo DB tables

Comment: Does put return a promise? If not, then wrap the entire call in a promise and call resolve() in your callback when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `.promise()` on the result of `.put()` call:

```js
const createdDoc = await docClient.put({ … }).promise();
```

See docs for [`AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.put()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property) and [`AWS.Request.promise()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#promise-property).